# Optimize mysql inner join query to use indexes

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a quite simple Mysql query that outputs products from category ordered by price descending.

```
SELECT
    p.id_product, p.price
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_category pc
ON (pc.id_product = p.id_product AND pc.id_category=1234)
GROUP BY pc.id_product
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

Since I have a lot of products in "product" table and even more product-category relations in "product_category" table this query lasts forever.

I have following indexes / primary keys defined:

- table "product" - primary key (id_product)
- table "product_category" - primary key (id_product, id_category), index(id_product), index(id_category)

But when I explain this query I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref                    | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pc    | index  | PRIMARY,id_product | id_product | 4       | NULL                   | 73779 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY    | 4       | mydb.pc.id_product     |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

so... Using temporary; Using filesort - I think that this is the problem why everything is running so slow.

Since this query is executed a lot of times from a closed-source software I can't change it. But I want to optimize table / indexes so this query will run faster. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: like I said - I can't change the query since it originates from closed-source software. So the only solution for me is to optimize the table(s)

Answer (score 1):

You have a constant condition on id_category, and a JOIN condition in id_product.

I believe that if you create an index on `(id_category, id_product)`, in this order, MySQL will be able to find relevant index entries for category 1234, and use them to find relevant `product_id`s to fetch from both tables.

Unfortunately I can't test this at the moment - I may try later.
If you can give it a try you will find out very quickly...

Comment: Thanks, Galz!!! I changed indeces positions and my query from 600ms changed to 62 ms!!!!